# Integrate $\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^5}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I find the value of
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^5}}dx.
$$

What I tried:

I input this into wolframalpha and observed that the answer is $B(2/5, 11/10)$. From this observation, I tried to manipulate the integral in order to obtain an expression that I know is equal to $B(2/5, 11/10)$, but I didn't manage to do this. For example, I tried decomposing the integral as
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{x+x^{-1/2}}{\sqrt{1+x^5}}dx
$$
so that the interval is now at least finite, but I didn't manage to get much from it. Also, now that the interval is $(0,1)$, one can compute the Taylor series around $x=0$ of the integral and interchange summation and integration. In that case, you get a sum involving binomials, which is not very hopeful.

Viewing this as a complex integral of some kind is always a possibility, but the integrand is not meromorphic (although I think you can make the complex integration method work in some cases), and the value it ought to be equal to is a bit complicated, so this approach has many difficulties. I don't think I could make this work.

Lastly, maybe the substitution $x\mapsto \tan(u)^{2/5}$ works.

Comment: Why would I get a negative vote?

Comment: You only stated a question, and this is what people on MSE does not like unless your integration is really non-trivial even for experts on integrations.

Comment: In your case, the integration seems to require Beta function (guessed from WolframAlpha answer.) I have no idea how to start, though.

Comment: @HanulJeon You are right, my bad. I described some of my thoughts, tho they are not very insightful. Now I'm trying the tan substitution, which I hadn't tried.

Comment: You can use $t=1+x^5$ and $dt=5x^4dx$.

Comment: If you use $x=\tan^{2/5}t,\,y=\sin^2t$, you get another form easily proven to be equivalent, $\frac15\operatorname{B}\left(\frac25,\,\frac{1}{10}\right)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the original integral is over $(0, \infty)$ and the beta integral is over $(0,1)$ suggests the transformation $$z = \frac{1}{1+x^5}, \quad x = z^{-1/5} (1 - z)^{1/5}, \quad dx = -\frac{1}{5} z^{-6/5} (1-z)^{-4/5} \, dz,$$
hence
$$\begin{align}
\int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{x}{(1+x^5)^{1/2}} \, dx &= -\frac{1}{5} \int_{z=1}^0 z^{-1/5} (1-z)^{1/5} z^{1/2} z^{-6/5} (1-z)^{-4/5} \, dz \\
&= \frac{1}{5} \int_{z=0}^1 z^{-9/10} (1-z)^{-3/5} \, dz \\
&= \frac{1}{5} B(1/10, 2/5) \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(1/10)\Gamma(2/5)}{5\Gamma(1/2)} \\
&= \frac{10 \Gamma(2/5)\Gamma(11/10)}{5 \cdot 2 \Gamma(3/2)} \\
&= B(2/5, 11/10).
\end{align}$$